# Web drive manager shutting down

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

i am trying to run protractor with code ample that i found online
right after i am writing *protractor config.js* the web drive manager shutting down. i have google chrome installed but firefox is my default browser and i wondered if its related to the problem

here is the code:
todo-spec.js

```
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function () {
  it('should add a todo', function () {
    browser.get('https://angularjs.org');

    element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first protractor test');
    element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();

    var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
    expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write first protractor test');

    // You wrote your first test, cross it off the list
    todoList.get(2).element(by.css('input')).click();
    var completedAmount = element.all(by.css('.done-true'));
    expect(completedAmount.count()).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

config.js

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['todo-spec.js']
};
```

Comment: the webdriver manager is up to date , protractor 2.5.0

Comment: What version of protractor and browser are you using? And you have you updated your webdriver-manger and tried to start it again? Update it using command - `webdriver-manager update`. Current version of selenium standalone is `2.47.1`.

Comment: i followed exacly this tutorial : https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/ the chrome browser is up to date  and i didnt installed saparetly selenium standalone

Comment: When you install protractor, it by defaults installs the selenium standalone with it as protractor is a wrapper over selenium. So if you run the command `webdriver-manager update` in your command prompt then it will show you if your selenium standalone is up to date or if it isn't.

Comment: chrome driver and selenium are up to date

Comment: Ok so does your selenium server throw an error before it stops running? If so, can you update that error in your question? The error that you have updated shows that selenium server has started but no errors in it.

Comment: no error...
"Attempting to shut down selenium nicely
17:07:45.113 INFO - Command request: shutDownSeleniumServer[, ] on session null
17:07:45.113 INFO - Shutdown command received
17:07:45.114 INFO - initiating shutdown
17:07:45.115 INFO - Got result: OK on session null
17:07:45.617 INFO - Shutting down...
Selenium Standalone has exited with code 0
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this issue because you are trying to run your protractor scripts using command `protractor conf.js` in the same command prompt window where you have started your selenium server using `webdriver-manger start`. You should use a different command prompt/terminal window to start your protractor tests. Follow these steps -

- Run `webdriver-manger start` in a command prompt window
- Open a new command prompt window
- Navigate to the folder where your protractor conf.js and scripts are written using `cd` command
- Now once you have navigated to the folder specified, run `protractor conf.js` command to start your automation

Hope it helps.